# How do I show the proper time on my intraday chart using AnyChart?

Tags: anychart

I have downloaded hourly stock data for AAPL for the past 30 days and am displaying a candlestick chart. The chart loads properly but the time shown for each bar is incorrect. I am in the Pacific time zone.

I tried changing the way the data table is created but none of the ideas below seem to help.

```
var dataTable = anychart.data.table(0);
var dataTable = anychart.data.table(0, '', 8);
```

I am using the same example as the one on the AnyChart website https://www.anychart.com/products/anystock/gallery/Stock_General_Features/Showing_Intraday_Data.php

Please see the following 2 images.

1. For the ORCL chart from the example on the AnyChart website, I clearly see the date and time (highlighted rectangle)
   [working example from AnyChart website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsOer.png)
2. For my chart (for AAPL hourly data), the time is off and it shows  "13 05 Nov 2021" etc.
   [Does not work for my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYN0F.png)

My source CSV file contains data as below (full CSV available at [this link](https://storage.googleapis.com/traderjazz/AAPL_1h.csv))

```
timestamp,gmtoffset,datetime,open,high,low,close,volume
1634650200000,0,2021-10-19 13:30:00,147.009994,148.820007,146.550003,148.759994,24069759
1634653800000,0,2021-10-19 14:30:00,148.759994,149.169998,148.229995,148.384994,13899143
1634657400000,0,2021-10-19 15:30:00,148.380004,148.759994,148.220001,148.759902,7623131
1634661000000,0,2021-10-19 16:30:00,148.759704,149.044998,148.5,148.889999,6263260
1634664600000,0,2021-10-19 17:30:00,148.884994,148.979995,148.479995,148.535003,4807906
1634668200000,0,2021-10-19 18:30:00,148.539993,148.837295,148.330001,148.460006,6333632
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AnyChart for responding so quickly via email.

The following snippet solves the issue with the tooltips and now I can see the proper date and time on the tooltip.

```
chart.tooltip().titleFormat(function() {
              return anychart.format.dateTime(this.x, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
            });
```

To set the proper legend, the following code does it:

```
plot.legend().title().useHtml(true);
            // configure the format of the legend title
            plot.legend().titleFormat(
              "<span style='font-weight:600'>" +
              "{%hoveredDate}{dateTimeFormat: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</span>"
            );
```